# Jquery Tools Overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

Hey guys, I've got a few quick questions.

Here is the site: [link text](http://www.ryancohengallery.com/?cat=1#)

I am using Jquery Tools overlay as shown here.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html

When you click the image, the popup shows up fine.

```
<img src="whatever.jpg" rel="#1" class="slideimg" alt="title" />
```

But whenever I try to use something else, say an image or a span, it wont work.

```
<a rel="#1" href="#">Click for Large</a>
```

Here is my Jquery for an image. I've tried replacing img with a and a few other things. Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("img[rel]").overlay();
```

});

Comment: I just tested this in firebug by adding $("a[rel]").overlay() and it worked for your "click here for large" anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second what Sea Hag says .. However if you are not able to get `$("a[rel]").overlay()` then one of the possible reasons for it cud also be that you have other  tags with rel attribute. Either you can do away with those or use a different  jquery selector .. I mean replace "a[re]" with some other selector like "#myid" to make it work.